# ArrayList vs Array and List

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, linked-list

I've been programming for quite a bit and recently started learning more pure Computer Science topics (for a job interview).

I know the difference between an Array and a LinkedList data structure, but now that I have started using Java I'm seeing this ArrayList, which I'm having trouble conceptualizing.

Web searches have only really shown me HOW to use them and WHEN to use them (benefits of each), but nothing can answer my question of:

What is an ArrayList? My assumption is that it is a list that maintains memory references to each element, making it also able to act like an array.

I also have a feeling since Java is open, that I should be able to look at the Class definition, but haven't figured out how to do that yet either.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to Google ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, I only got results about how to use it, when to use it, and what the methods/properties are. I'm wondering what the underlying data structure looks like. Is it an Array or a List or somehow both.

Comment: By logic, I assume that an ArrayList is a more concrete version of a List.
It is structured as a List but has methods which are similar to an Array's method.

Comment: You can look at the `ArrayList` source code in your IDE (in IntelliJ, select `ArrayList` in code, then CTRL + left mouse click). You'll see that an `ArrayList` is essentially a wrapped `Object[]` with a load of convenient methods for inserting, removing etc.

Comment: Thanks @pbabcdefp!! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to think of it as a data-structure that lets you enjoy both worlds, the quick-access to an index like with an array and the infinite growth of a list. Of course, there are always trade-offs.

`ArrayList` is actually a wrapper to an array. Every time the size of the array ends, a new array, twice the size, is created and all the data from the original array is copied to the new one.

From the java doc:

> **Resizable-array implementation of the List interface**. Implements all
>   optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null. In
>   addition to implementing the List interface, this class provides
>   methods to manipulate the size of the array that is used internally to
>   store the list. (This class is roughly equivalent to Vector, except
>   that it is unsynchronized.) **The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and
>   listIterator operations run in constant time**. The **add operation runs
>   in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n)
>   time**. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly
>   speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the
>   LinkedList implementation.
>
> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of
>   the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at
>   least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an
>   ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth
>   policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has
>   constant amortized time cost.
>
> An application can increase the capacity of an ArrayList instance
>   before adding a large number of elements using the ensureCapacity
>   operation. This may reduce the amount of incremental reallocation.

This allows **O(1)** access for most of the operations like it would take with an array. Once in a while you need to pay for this performance with an insert operation that takes much longer though.

This is called [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) complexity. Each operation takes only **O(1)** aside for those times you need to double the size of the array. In those time you would pay **O(n)** but if you average it over n operations, the average time taken is only **O(1)** and not **O(n)**.

Let's take an example:

We have an array of size 100 (n=100). You make 100 insert operations (to different indices) and each of them takes only **O(1)**, of course that all get-by-index operations also take **O(1)** (as this is an array). On the 101 insertion, there's no more more capacity in the array so the ArrayList will create a new array, the size of 200, copy all the values to it (**O(n)** operations) and then insert the 101st item. Until you fill out the array to 200 items, all of the operations would take **O(1)**.

Comment: Thanks!! I hadn't heard of amortized analysis before. That makes sense though. Seems like it makes sense to use it in time complexity, but in space wouldn't you end up with O(2n) pretty often? Is this just assuming that the objects aren't significantly large and the device can handle it? I guess the books have been going through have been more theory than practice. I'm not planning on having 10^20 elements in my mobile app whereas computer science books shy away from using 2x memory.

Comment: In complexity analysis O(2n) is the same as O(n). If you're talking about Android app, you should not be worried about the overhead memory of ArrayList, you have enough space most probably. Unless you're creating billions of objects.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again! A little off topic, but is O(n) pronounced (like in an interview) as "big oh of n" or some other way?

Comment: I think you would say Oh-En. But I'm not a native English speaker so I'm really not sure :)

Answer (score 5):

An `ArrayList` is a list that is directly backed by an array.  More specifically, it's backed by an array that is dynamically resized.  You can read a bit more about it in [its source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java?av=f); there are some pretty good comments to it.

The reason that this is significant is due to how a `LinkedList` is implemented - as a traditional collection of nodes and references to other nodes.  This has performance impacts in indexing and traversal, whereas with an `ArrayList`, since it's backed by an array, all one needs to do is index into the specific array to retrieve the value.

Comment: So, if it's backed by an Array, does that mean that adding/inserting/deleting issues tags costly, or is it somehow optimized? I guess dynamic array are the next topic I'll study up on! Thanks!

Comment: Depends on where you are with respect to your capacity.  There's the potential to incur a O(n) cost when resizing the array (if you're out of capacity or near your threshhold), but if you're somewhere in the middle, it's O(1).  Removal would be O(n-i) since you have to shift your remaining values over to the left to fill in the missing values.

Comment: The *amortized* cost for inserting new elements *at the end* of the array is constant and likewise for removing them.  However, if you insert / delete elements from the middle of the array, you'll pay for linear cost as you'll have to shift n / 2 elements on average.

Comment: Thanks!! I like that this explains each method.

Comment: Yeah - it's Javadoc and it's pulling from the same source [that the API is using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  This shows the in-line comments as those have more nuggets about implementation details.